# Python overwrite print output from nth character

Tags: string, python-2.7

I was wondering if there was a way to overwrite an existing line of print output starting from the nth character. So instead of overwriting everything like this

```
sys.stdout.write("\r 5: elephant")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

you would replace the existing line from say after the :

Comment: 1. Reprint the first part of the line each time.  2. Backspace to that point, rather than using `\r` to go back to the start of the line.  3. Use the `curses` library to be able to place characters wherever on the screen you want.

Comment: is there an easy way to access the current printed output? The reason for this being a problem is that this arises at the inferface between separate functions that are each nested in other functions...

Comment: Once flushed, `sys.stdout` is technically a write-only stream so you don't get the chance to see what's already printed to the console in front of the current position and therefore you cannot really 'skip' to it to change it willy-nilly. You either need to keep a track of how many characters you printed and then backtrack that many characters, or you need to buffer your whole line, issue a carriage return and then print the first `n` characters before printing your change.

Comment: Can you backspace with stdout? I've tried \b but that doesn't seem to work?